# Как отдельно запустить второй скрипт питон

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

Нужно запустить второй скрипт, независимо от первого вместе с параметрами.

Пытался создавать поток на функцию во втором файле, но работает не так, как мне нужно. Подсказали, что нужно именно открывать отдельный файл.

Пытался открывать так:

```
subprocess.Popen("script.py 1235454, 5", shell=True)
```

и так:

```
os.system("script.py 1")
```

но пишет, что файл `script.py` не найден.

Comment: Может полный путь до фала поможет?

Answer (score 2):

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen("python script.py 1235454, 5", shell=True)
```